# Android Custom Adapter out of bound exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

While coding an android app in Kotlin I came across this error: 
[image]

I am using the [OpenWeatherMapApi](https://openweathermap.org/api) and from the API I am trying to grab the Forecast Data. And I was able to pull the Forecast data thanks to okhttp3 and Gson but now my issue is displaying that data. I created and a new class for a custom ArrayAdapter where I try to display in the textView that I created, but I am completely at a loss as to why I keep getting the error the array shouldn't have a size of 1 but it ends up having it

**Code**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.weather_row.view.*

class ForecastAdapter(val forecast: Forecast) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastData>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return forecast.list.count()

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ForecastData {
        val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.weather_row, p0, false)
        return ForecastData(cellForRow)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ForecastData, p1: Int) {
        val getWeather = forecast.list[p1]
        val  clouds = getWeather.weather[p1]
        p0.view.textView_text_clouds.text = clouds.main
    }

}

class ForecastData(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){


}
```

Comment: The problem is likely with `getWeather.weather[p1]`. The `weather` "list" usually only has one item. You should be using `getWeather.weather[0]`.

Comment: Alright that actually worked! Thank you! How do I accept this as the right answer since it is in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with

```
getWeather.weather[p1]
```

The `weather` "list" isn't really a list. It usually only has one element.

Use this instead:

```
getWeather.weather[0]
```